# how does Pandas dataframe index differ from other columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to use Pandas in order to exploit `dataframe.interpolate` for filling in gaps in a time series, but having problems setting up an index that that function wants.

It brings up a more general question:  A Pandas dataframe consists of a number of *columns*, each consisting of items of one `dtype`.  There's also a *row index*, which looks an awful lot like a column to me.

So... what's the difference between a dataframe (row) index and all other columns?  For example, I might have thought that there was a requirement that all index entries be unique, like a SQL database key, but it appears that's not the case?  So, again, what things are special about the row index compared to non-index columns?

Comment: Could you supply your code? No the index does not need to be unique

Answer (score 0):

Index  allows the loc command to call specified rows. If there is a duplication you can call all duplicates. If you want to specify one row, either use hierarchical indexing or else iloc (the numerical position).

Duplication of values within the index is quite important because it facilitates hierarchical indexing. This is very useful in pandas

So an index is a row that you assigned as an index. It is also really useful to remove a column (by assigning it to an index), manipulate the dataframe and reintroduce the index back as a column.

Interpolate is a very cool command, but from memory it only works on columns. If you want to interpolate the index,

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then interpolate that new column and then

```
 df.set_index('column interpolated', inplace=True)
```

For time series consider the `roll` function. You can use it to move across missing data.

Comment: Michael, I have a time-series in the form of a two-column table where the first column is a time-stamp and the second is a value for that time-stamp; time-stamps are unique but some of the values are missing.  I'm building a dataframe in which the index comes from the time-stamps, the single non-index column is the values.   What I'm trying to do is find the missing value using "interpolate" with method = "time", which I understand is doing "weighted linear interpolation" using the DatetimeIndex.

Comment: For this interpolation.. you might consider an apply or lambda x style function. This seems a bit advanced from my memory of interpolate in pandas

Comment: You might consider moving away from a long format... Lots of possibilities

Comment: I think my problem with Pandas "interpolate" was that it didn't allow me to control which column(s) I want to interpolate, and which column to use as the abscissa for the interpolation.  So, I switched to doing the interpolation using ```scipy.interpolate``, which provides these controls and provides a wide range of kinds of interpolation.  And/but, for the original problem, it turned out that linear interpolation was the most accurate in filling in the gaps.  Oh, well...